# How do I complete the guide?

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, apache-nifi

So I recetly got interested in making a twitter monitor. I followed this guide (link at the bottom) and I got stuck at the second step. I simply don’t know how I should add the second code to first, could someone help me please.

https://medium.com/@jdayllon/simple-twitter-monitor-with-elasticsearch-opendistro-15cb52ef420a

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy/paste the Nifi section between the `kibana` sub-section and the `volumes` section, like this:

```
  ...
  kibana:
    image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch-kibana:1.1.0
    container_name: odfe-kibana
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    expose:
      - "5601"
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: https://odfe-node1:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: https://odfe-node1:9200
    networks:
      - odfe-net

  nifi:
    image: apache/nifi:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080 # Unsecured HTTP Web Port
    environment:
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT=8080
      - NIFI_ELECTION_MAX_WAIT=1 min
    volumes:
      - ./nifi-data:/opt/nifi-data/
      - ./python:/opt/nifi-python
    extra_hosts:
      - "elasticsearch:odfe-node1"
    networks:
      - odfe-net

volumes:
  odfe-data1:
  odfe-data2:

networks:
  odfe-net:
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I’m currently in school so I’ll try it at home, can I leave those 3 dots at the top there or do i delete them?

Comment: The three dots at the top simply mean that there's more content before `kibana` but I haven't copied it. I suggest you read a bit more about [Docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/) before going further.